# Set a specific version name with doctrine:migrations:diff

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

I'm discovering Symfony and Doctrine.
I was able to generate a file containing a class for my migration using

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff
```

It's great but the name of my file (and my class) is : Version20160714233422.

It's not really understable (even though it's the date) and I would like to call it Version1 for example.

I guess it would be possible to change manually the names but is there a way to do it automatically ?

I looked on the help :

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff --help
```

but this feature doesn't seems to be implemented. Am I wrong ?

Is there a reason it's not possible ? 
Does setting a code like 0.1, 0.2... is a bad idea ?

If someone could explain this to me it would be very much appreciated !

Comment: While I understand what you are asking I do not understand the motivation behind it. If you have the date you can sort it (and have it numbered) as well know when that migration was generated. So you have at least one piece of information more than you'd have by just calling it Version1

Comment: Thank you for your comment Kero. I asked because, in the eventuality of two features developped in the same time, it's possible that the diff of the second feature was made before the one who would be pushed on master in first. If that happend it would be hard to know which version correspond to the feature. (I hope you understand what I'm trying to say, I'm french)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I guess you would like to use a subversion repository. Lets see why the version name is generated as a timestamp in format `Ymdhis` there is a small chance that two developers working on the same project will generate the migration in exact same second. Which would resolve in conflict state.

On the other hand, sequential naming would resolve in conflict states very often. Two developers have the branch from master and both see last migration version `Version20`. They both decide to create new migration with name `Version21`.

That is why the migrations is generated with the timestamp name. If you want to change it you have to do it manually.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jakub. I answered a comment on my question about why I wanted to do that. I guess it's all about organisation... Anyway, since it works like that, I suppose I won't spend time renaming everything… Thanks !